# $\int_{t=-\infty}^x (G(t)-F(t))\mbox{d}t\geq 0\forall x$ and $\frac{\mbox{d}F(t)}{\mbox{d}G(t)}$ increasing $\Longrightarrow G(x)\geq F(x)\forall x$?

Tags: probability, inequality, probability-distributions

As in the title I wonder if the relation at the left side implies the one at the right side. Better to rewrite it clearly

Given are:

$\mbox{Info} (1)\rightarrow$ $\int_{t=-\infty}^x (G(t)-F(t))\mbox{d}t\geq 0\forall x$

$\mbox{Info} (2)\rightarrow$ $\frac{\mbox{d}F(t)}{\mbox{d}G(t)}=\frac{f(t)}{g(t)}$ increasing function in $t$

> Question: Do $1$ and $2$ imply $G(x)\geq F(x)\forall x$?

$G$ and $F$ are probability distribution functions and $f$ and $g$ are corresponding density functions.

Thank you very much in advance..

Comment: Are $1-$ and $2-$ supposed to be item identifiers in a list? If so, the way you have it typeset makes it *very* easy to confuse it with something very different!

Comment: @cardinal yes sure. They are only items but later I say do $1$ and $2$ imply ... Therefore I thought it would be clear. The question is about giving a counterexample that a second order stochastically dominance doesn't imply first order stochastically dominance. For all counter examples $f/g$ was not an increasing function. Therefore I conjectured this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received an answer to this problem at MO. It is based on Harris inequality. The result is that only the increasing likelihood ratio alone implies $G(x)\geq F(x)\,\forall x$. You can see the complete answer from [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/155677/does-second-order-stochastical-domination-with-increasing-likelihood-ratio-imply).